# Which condition does not satisfy that E [X + Y] is equal to E [X] + E [Y]?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Since E[X + Y] has linearity, it can be resolved to E[X] + E[Y]. However, it is said that this method does not always work.

E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]

What are the conditions under which the above equation cannot be achieved? and why?

Comment: When $X$ is a Cauchy-distributed variable and $Y=-X$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Aye, when the expectation of the individuals are undefined you cannot say that the expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations.  (And in Raskolnikov's excellent example, the expectation of the sum is zero.)